# Using JSP, is the deployment descriptor (web.xml) obsolete?

Tags: jsp

I should preface this question by saying that I am new to JavaServer Pages. I have been researching the purpose and use of the deployment descriptor (commonly referred to as web.xml). I found [this document](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/pdf/ajax/Servlet+JSP-Review.pdf) which says that some Java annotations can be used to describe things that would typically be put in the deployment descriptor. So, my question is:

1. Using the latest version of JSP, is it possible to **only** use annotations to describe what would otherwise go in the deployment descriptor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is sort of the point.  Rather than using `web.xml`, you would annotate your classes that fulfill those various functions.  A Servlet would be annotated with `@WebServlet`, a Filter with `@WebFilter`, etc.

Here's a good article: http://www.servletworld.com/servlet-tutorials/servlet3/new-features.html

Note that this is a common trend in Java EE - the move away from XML configuration to annotations.  Spring, for example, is following this trend with the v3.1 introduction of `@Configuration` classes which can take the place of XML config files.